# Step function for variable selection is not working

Tags: r, linear-regression, variable-selection

I am trying to do a variable selection using the `step()` function in R. But it keep getting an error. 
Then I found out that now there is no basic `step()` function like previously. There is a step function in the `lmerTest` package for mixed models.

Does anyone know an alternative function for this ?

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the results of `find("step")` and `packageVersion("lmerTest")` please? (With version 3.0.1 of `lmerTest` loaded, I couldn't reproduce the error ...()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was masked by lemerTest package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `stats::step` (I assume it is the function you want to use) is masked by another package (probably `lmerTest`).

Did you try with the package name?

```
stats::step(regmodel, direction = "forward")
```